# Energy released during fission using equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, nuclear-physics

Im trying to caculate energy released during this equation.
LHS:
Binding energy of $neutron=939.576$ Mev
Binding energy of U$-235=1783.65$ Mev

RHS:
Binding energy of Tc$-112=936.32$ Mev
Binding energy of of In$-122=1038.22$ Mev
Binding energy of $2$ neutrons $= 1879.15221$ Mev

Difference between LHS and RHS is  $1130$ Mev which is my answer

The answer is $190$ Mev apparently as the mark scheme ignores the neutrons?

They do it this way:

LHS:
Binding energy of U$-235=1783.65$ Mev

RHS:
Binding energy of Tc$-112=936.32$ Mev
Binding energy of of In$-122=1038.22$ Mev

Difference between LHS and RHS is $190$ Mev which is the correct answer

So my question is why did they ignore the neutrons in the equation to calculate energy released during fission?

$$^1_0\text{n}+^{235}_{92}\text{U}\rightarrow ^{112}_{43}\text{Tc}+^{112}_{49}\text{In}+2^1_0\text{n}$$

Comment: You are mixing up rest energy and binding energy. A lone neutron is not bound to anything.

Comment: Ok I see ,thankyou @JonCuster